# Is it possible to create a lint warning for not allowing using two annotations simutaneously

Tags: java, annotations

There are created two annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface A {
    String value() default "";
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface B {
    boolean encoded() default false;

    String value() default "";
}
```

Is it possible to create a lint warning/error if these annotations are used simultaneously in the code, like

```
@A("")
@B("") // display a lint warning/error that user should use only one of them
fun ...
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such way. If they are so connected, why not have only one annotation with some proper attributes? Maybe we have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: You could create an annotation processor that checks if the two annotations are present on the same element and, if so, emit an error and cause compilation to fail.